# iPhone / iPad - Safari browser cookie not saved when terminating app

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cookies, safari

On iPhone/iPad (iOS) - using Safari or Chrome browser, persistent cookie (with expiration date) is not getting saved to the browser if the app is terminated (closed/killed by swiping up the app).

Is this a code/cookie problem or native iOS/browser behavior issue?

This issue happens in any scenario where you close the app after the cookie has been dropped.
You could also try refreshing the page one, twice, or three times and terminate the page.
Next time you open the app, you'll notice the cookie was never saved.

I've created a codepen.io for this:
https://codepen.io/jussjosh/pen/KLyqxr

**JavaScript:**

```
// find elements
var beforeCookie = $("#beforeCookie")
var afterCookie = $("#afterCookie")
var btnAdd = $("#btnAdd")
var btnDel = $("#btnDel")

// Cookie Exists
if (document.cookie.match(/MyCookie/)) {
  afterCookie.show();
} else {
  beforeCookie.show();
}

// Add/Delete Cookie
function dropCookie(name, expire) {
  var cookieName = name;
  var days = expire;
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires=" + date.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cookieName + "=1; " + expires + ";domain=; path=/";
}

// Button: Add Cookie
btnAdd.on("click", function(){
  dropCookie('MyCookie', 1);
  beforeCookie.hide();
  afterCookie.show();
})

// Button: Delete Cookie
btnDel.on("click", function(){
  dropCookie('MyCookie', -100);
  beforeCookie.show();
  afterCookie.hide();
})
```

Use this Debug mode to view the code on Mobile browser:
https://s.codepen.io/jussjosh/debug/KLyqxr/WPkLYNqpxyOM

**Banner message - before cookie is dropped:**
[image: Before Cookie Drop Banner]

**Banner message - after "MyCookie" is dropped:**
[image: After Cookie Drop Banner]

The page above basically adds or deletes a cookie called "MyCookie" when you click on the button.
When cookie is dropped and you refresh, you will see the "Cookie got dropped!" banner consistently.
You can confirm that "MyCookie" was dropped and it has an expiration date of 1 day if you connect your iPhone to a Mac and use Safari's developer tool.

However, after you terminate the app, and relaunch Safair you will notice that "MyCookie" is no longer available, and the banner defaults back to:
"Click button to save cookie for 1 day".

This happens even if you refresh the page several times.

I tried like refreshing the page more than 7 times or more, then killed the app, and relaunch Safari, **then** the cookie seemed to persist!
It seems like it's not the number of times refreshed, but maybe **time** based.